# ML.NET better looking metrics

Tags: c#, ml.net

In `v0.9` we had nice looking metrics:

[image]

In `v1.4`, everything is simplier:

```
Console.WriteLine("----------Testing model----------\n");
var testData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<CancerData>("Cancer-test.csv", hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ';');
var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(model.Transform(testData), labelColumnName: "Target");

Console.WriteLine("----------Score----------");
Console.WriteLine($"Accuracy: {metrics.Accuracy}");
Console.WriteLine($"F1 Score: {metrics.F1Score}");
Console.WriteLine($"Log Loss: {metrics.LogLoss}");
Console.WriteLine($"Entropy: {metrics.Entropy}");
```

Is it possible to get that good looking metrics from older `ML.NET` in newer one?

Answer (score 2):

In `v0.9`, the output was written to the console by default, and there was no way to shut it off. In versions `1.0` and later it is no longer written by default, but you can enable writing this output to the console with the following code:

```cs
mlContext.Log += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
```